# handsontable how to set cell to invalid manually

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have some handsontable which I use to update information into the db.

The first step is: I validate the data, then if an error occurred I fill the row with red color else I just save the information

Here come the problem:
I call ajax request hard coded I change the style of the td or tr
But after I change some value or use the scroll in the table, it calls the inside draw function, and all the colors are backto default

How Do I set the cell to be invalid ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method 'getCellMeta(row, col') to get the cell data then edit the property 'valid' of that cell.

e.g.

```
var cellMeta = $("#table").handsontable('getCellMeta', row, col);
cellMeta.valid = false;
// Force re-rendering
$("#table").handsontable('render');
```

The getCellMeta(row,col) method only accept numeric parameters. Do not put the property name of your object as column number.

Best regards,

Answer (score 8):

On version 0.21, maybe newer version than the other answer, this is what worked for me, and seems a bit cleaner:

```
myHandsOnTable.setCellMeta(rowIndex, colIndex, 'valid', false);
myHandsOnTable.render();
```

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.21.0/Core.html#setCellMeta